# How can I test a production iOS App Store build?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm new to iPhone development and i'm not sure how to test the actually binary that will be sent to Apple. Today I released a build that works great on my local device but the released App Store version did not work and hung on launch.

I'm trying to figure out how I can test my production builds so this doesn't happen again.

I tried creating an ad-hoc binary and saved the ipa to my desktop, then imported into iTunes. The app synced and downloaded but remained dark and said 'waiting..'.

I signed up for Test Flight and it said my IPA was created for production and the sdk could not be found.

Do I need to research ad-hoc builds and profiles? This seems to be getting confusing really quickly and i'm not sure where to start looking/learning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create an archive to submit to the AppStore, it is saved under the organizer (Press Command + Shift + 2 to open Organizer).
You can save the same archive for Ad-hoc distribution as a .IPA file, and then install it using iTunes or TestFlight.

In the Organizer, just select the right archive, click 'Distribute', and select 'Ad-hoc distribution' and sign the IPA with your Ad-Hoc distribution profile (if you haven't created an ad-hoc distribution profile, create one at developer.apple.com, download it and double-click on it to import it to your Mac OS Keychain) to generate the .IPA file.

As long as you re-sign your AppStore archive with an ad-hoc distribution profile, it should install and execute on your test devices.

Comment: This will not work as the production/release/live version will be signed with a distribution profile which stops you running it on your device without it going through the App Store.

Comment: I just edited my answer with the code signing bit.
He should select an ad-hoc distribution profile. As long as the signing profile is a valid one, the app will execute the same as it will from the app store.

Comment: Thanks! This made it much easier to understand. The only thing that was different is on my xcode I couldn't right click on the archive and dist., I had to single click and then hit the dist. button , then ad-hoc. Now that I have it signed with the ad-hoc it's working in both iTunes and TestFlight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps hopefully it will work

1. Delete the application from your iPhone.
2. Create a new Adhoc Distribution provisioning profile, make your the devices you want to run on are included in that profile.
3. Make sure the certificate associated with the newly created profile has a valid private/public key pair.
4. After creating an archive, see the build must be created with the newly created profile(From a drop down that comes after archive).
5. If the problem persists, to verify rename the .ipa to .zip go to payload folder right click .app and show package contents see the embedded profile shows the correct profile and have the devices added.